# Method to get all points' coordinates OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I have a rectangle and a circle. Of the circle i have all points' coordinates because i calculate them to draw it using math rules. the rectangle in drawed using two triangles so 4 vertices. Now these are free to translate and route in the plan and i want to determinate when one of them touch the other one. so I thought that this happens when one of the coordinates of one of them is the same that one of the others of the other object. The problem is that i haven't an array of all coordinates of the rectangle. Is there a method that return all coordinates that a drawed triangles and not only the vertices' ones in OpenGL?

Comment: What you are trying to do is really, really inefficient. The intersection between a circle and a rectangle can be calculated analytically without much hassle.

Comment: becouse i don't have the equation of the circumference and the equation of the rectangle. i know that i can caluclate it but during the animation the two figure must transformate in others and i can't do using geometric transformations. so to have the equations is useless for me and i prefer to work with coordinates

Comment: That doesn't change the overall picture. You still should use the input primitives you are drawing, not the rasterized results on screen.

Comment: so i should to calculate the pointers to my self and work with it? (the pointers of the rectangle?)

Comment: no. the rectangle is either just 2 triangles, or 4 lines. There is no point in calcualting indidual points on its boundary.

Comment: sorry i don't understand as well.. and how can i detect if the two figures is intersectioned without using coordinates?

Comment: @P.Carlino: The point is that you *compute those coordinates*. You transform the rectangle's corners exactly as you would when you render it, just on the CPU. Then you use rectangle-to-circle collision detection formulas. You should not put this on OpenGL.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas actually, sometimes we get forced to solve such problems in openGL, in case there is transparency involved and one fragment intersects other, for example. Yes, that's ineffective, that leads to use of deferred rendering, but that happens but should be avoided otherwise

Comment: I solved it creating a border render

Answer (score 0):

There is method to record coords and commands supplied to OpenGL, using stencil buffer, but that's a rather inefficient way, because you would need to decompile commands inside buffer.

If you didn't had an array of coordinates , you already used the most inefficient way to supply geometry to OpenGL:

```
glBegin(...);
glVertex3f(...);
glVertex3f(...);
...
glVertex3f(...);
glEnd();
```

The more efficient way to  do that is to use vertex buffer, which automatically requires to have array of coordinates. With large amount of vertices, VBO methods is times faster than vertex by vertex copying.

OpenGL doesn't store the coordinates you've supplied to it any longer than it is required,  i.e. until rasterization. Whole goal of OpenGL is to create image on screen, not to solve some abstract tasks.

Comment: And I know it .. infact  I used buffer and vbo